# Compression Digital vs Analog

Tags: compression

Anyone care to explain the fine points in the difference between analog and digital compression. I understand that the most apparent difference is the method in which the signal is compressed.

I’ve heard people say that analog equipment results in a better sound over digital equipment. Is this true?

Comment: I think the second paragraph of your question is not suited for this site, since its explicit asking for an individual opinion... I am not an expert with this stuff, but I prefer the one which fits the sound im looking for. Sometimes analog fits better, sometimes digital fits better

Comment: That why the second paragraph start off “In your opinion,”

Comment: Yes, and that's off topic for this site. I'm afraid this might get your question flagged and possibly removed. Maybe you can extract the second paragraph and ask it in the chat. This way you might get some answers for your first paragraph.

Comment: I've edited the question to increase its chance of survival!

Comment: Still getting the hang of the site, mind telling me why the fact that I asked for others opinion regarding a question would prompt my question to be flagged or removed? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: There's an explanation of analog vs digital compression here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Design

Comment: There's a rule against 'opinion-based' questions and one against asking for recommendations of specific products.  (Music is an art, and WILL involve opinion.  But the ethos of SE prefers questions with binary answers.)  A bit of rephrasing can usually deflect those who are minded to police us too strictly.

Comment: For a slice of personal opinion - I think people who still say analog is better than digital stopped listening properly about the time the CD came out, mid 80s. The world has moved on a whole lot since then.

Answer (score 2):

No, the most apparent difference is what different compressors SOUND like.

Yes, there's a passion for 'retro' gear in some parts of the recording world.

If 'what a 1950s Fairchild tube compressor sounds like'  (minus the hum) is your definition of perfection, I expect you'll be able to detect how a digital emulation isn't QUITE identical.  (Though computers have an uncomfortable habit of casually overcoming 'they'll NEVER manage THAT!' barriers.)

'It's not about the gear' becomes increasingly true as high-quality recording hardware becomes increasingly affordable and digital emulations become increasingly accurate.   Good.  It can be 'all about the music'.